# Ubuntu 15.10. Weird error message and the desktop image doesn't boot through usbstick

Tags: live-usb, 15.10

I've downloaded the latest Ubuntu Desktop 15.10 and used Rufus to make an image to a usbstick. This has worked in the past for me. But recently i've hade to by a new motherboard and a new CPU because the old ones got broken.

I've booted up from the motherboards bootmenu and i get the starting booting screen with that keyboard and a person or whatever it is. And then i get this [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nugdV.jpg)

I don't know how to retrieve the logfile from an installation DVD(Usb).

Motherboard: ASUS M5A99FX PRO R2.0..... CPU: AMD FX-6350 Black Edition.....Regular usbstick i know is working properly because i've installed Windows 10 with it earlier this day. WesternDigital Sata HDDs and one Cruical SSD. Radeon R9 290X.

Everything works great in Windows. When i tried to boot up Debian's installer i get some ata7:00 error message.

I don't know how to retrieve errorlogs from a usbstick.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work. Ubuntu doesn't like SATA6G_E12 connectors. So I've changed my SSD and my DVDrom to regular SATA connectors and now everything works great.